# How to limit a div by a max-width, but keep to the width of interior elements when less?

Tags: html, responsive-design, css

Ok, so I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <img src="..."> //Each of width 100px
    <img src="...">
    <img src="...">
    ... //Continues depending on user - retrieved using PHP
</div>
```

My CSS has the following:

```
.element{
max-width: 400px;
}
```

But my issue is that when there is only one img shown, the width of the div is still 400px? What I'm trying to do is keep it the width of the interior elements, e.g. When there is one image, the div will be 100px wide; when there are 2 it will be 200px wide and then when it gets to 4 it goes down to the next row and continues like this at a width of 400px with the height now changing to compensate for more images.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this? I've tried using a combination of min-width/max-width, but I just can't seem to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
.element{
max-width: 400px;
display:inline-block;
}
```